# Saber a dimensão de uma imagem no Android

Tags: java, android

Eu estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em Android. Preciso pegar o RGB de uma determinada imagem em 5 pontos específicos da imagem. conforme demonstrado abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando o seguinte código para capturar o RGB da imagem:

```
    int color = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

    int red = Color.red(color);
    int blue = Color.blue(color);
    int green = Color.green(color);
    int alpha = Color.alpha(color);
```

- Os pontos definidos na ilustração acima são apenas um exemplo!
- Eu imagino que para determinar o ponto que quero pegar o RGB, isso é, nos pontos definidos por mim, **eu preciso saber quais as dimensões de uma imagem.**

***Minha questão é:***

1. Como posso capturar as dimensões de uma imagem? Isso é, suas dimensões em largura e altura?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/material/palette-colors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando, a primeiro momento, que esteja usando um `ImageView`, uma opção é criar uma variável do tipo [`ViewTreeObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html) e usar o método `addOnPreDrawListener` para ficar "observando e ouvindo" a *view* específica na medida em que é lançada na aplicação, indiferentemente da resolução do dispositivo. Veja:

- `getMeasuredHeight()` : Resgata a altura do `ImageView`
- `getMeasuredWidth()` : Resgata o comprimento do `ImageView`

Veja abaixo:

```
final ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

        int height = iv.getMeasuredHeight();
        int width = iv.getMeasuredWidth();

        return true;
    }
});
```

**XML**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    />
```

---

No [**Kotlin**](http://kotlination.com) usando *[extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html)*, isso fica bem mais simples. Veja:

```
iv.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
    override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
        iv.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
        val height = iv.measuredHeight
        val width = iv.measuredWidth

        return true
    }
})
```